# Oracle need a query like what INFORMATION_SCHEMA provides for MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I'm in need of a single query that produces output similar to what INFORMATION_SCHEMA provides for MySQL.

For instance, in MySQL, I have:

```
SELECT 
  TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, IS_NULLABLE, COLUMN_TYPE, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, COLUMN_KEY
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE
TABLE_NAME='person' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='test';
```

For Oracle, I'm having a hard time getting a column specifying whether or not the COLUMN_NAME is the primary key for the table.  I have:

```
SELECT 
  utc.COLUMN_ID, utc.TABLE_NAME, utc.COLUMN_NAME, utc.DATA_TYPE, utc.DATA_LENGTH, utc.NULLABLE
FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS utc
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'PERSON';
```

Does anyone have a way of doing this by amending the query through a LEFT JOIN or similar?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint:  `all_tables`, `all_tab_columns`.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: . . I don't downvote.  Your question seems reasonable.  Perhaps the anonymous downvoter thought you could find this information easily using Google -- but without a comment, it is impossible to know the reason.

Comment: Sorry @GordonLinoff didn't mean to direct it at you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference...

```
SELECT 
  utc.COLUMN_ID, utc.TABLE_NAME, utc.COLUMN_NAME, utc.DATA_TYPE, utc.DATA_LENGTH, utc.NULLABLE,
  (SELECT cons.status
   FROM all_constraints cons, all_cons_columns cols
   WHERE 
     cols.table_name = 'PERSON'
     AND cols.column_name = utc.COLUMN_NAME
     AND cons.constraint_type = 'P'
     AND cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name
     AND cons.owner = cols.owner) AS IS_PRIMARY_KEY
FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS utc
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'PERSON';
```